# Trouble converting a simple function to a Factory or Service using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I've searched SO and the web for a long time but still can't find the right answer to my problem. Although there are a lot of threads addressing function to Factory/Service conversion, none seem to apply to my current situation. I frequently use Services for setters/getters and $http calls without issue so I'm struggling to find out why I'm having so much trouble converting this simple function to a Factory or Service.

I have a table of data that I am paginating using the following code in my HTML:

`<tr data-ng-repeat="book in filtered = (books | filter: query) | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">`

I'm then using a simple function to show the "Next" button when the table contains more than one page and to hide it if there is only one page or the user has reached the last page. I do so using `ng-show="showNext(filtered)"`. The function looks like this:

```
 $scope.showNext = function(filtered){

 var numPages = Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize),
     lastPage = $scope.currentPage+1;

 if(filtered.length > $scope.pageSize && lastPage < numPages){
   return true;
 }else if(filtered.length > $scope.pageSize && lastPage === numPages){
   return false;
 }else{
   return false;
 }
};
```

This function works great in the Controller by itself, however, I would now like to use it across multiple controllers. My first attempt was to use a factory so I wrote this:

```
app.factory('PaginationService', function(){

var pagination = {};

pagination.showNext = function(data, pageSize, currentPage, filtered){
  var numPages = Math.ceil(data.length/pageSize),
      lastPage = currentPage+1;

  if(filtered.length > pageSize && lastPage < numPages){
    return true;
  }else if(filtered.length > pageSize && lastPage === numPages){
    return false;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
};

return pagination;

});
```

And then I'm passing the Factory as a dependency in my Controller and calling it like this:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;

$scope.showNext = function(filtered){
  PaginationService.showNext(data, $scope.pageSize, $scope.currentPage, filtered);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, but no errors are thrown so I'm having trouble diagnosing why that is.

I've also tried making it a Service like this:

```
 this.showNext = function(data, pageSize, currentPage, filtered){
   var numPages = Math.ceil(data.length/pageSize),
       lastPage = currentPage+1;

   if(filtered.length > pageSize && lastPage < numPages){
     return true;
   }else if(filtered.length > pageSize && lastPage === numPages){
     return false;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
 };
```

Then I pass the Service as a dependency and call it in my Controller like this:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;

$scope.showNext = function(filtered){
  MyService.showNext(data, $scope.pageSize, $scope.currentPage, filtered);
}
```

I get the same result, it doesn't work but no errors are thrown.

Overall I'm really just attempting to use this as a shared function between my controllers that I can pass parameters to. Some of those parameters will be $scope variables from the Controller as seen above. I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in implementation in controller

```
$scope.showNext = function(filtered){
  PaginationService.showNext(data, $scope.pageSize, $scope.currentPage, filtered);
}
```

Nothing is returned from `$scope.showNext()` so in view it will always evaluate to `undefined`

Add `return` so that the boolean returned by service function gets returned to the controller scope function

```
$scope.showNext = function(filtered){
   return  PaginationService.showNext(data, $scope.pageSize, $scope.currentPage, filtered);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was as simple as that. I couldn't thank you enough! That explains why my other Services worked without issue and this one didn't. Thank you again for the quick and correct answer to my issue, your a life saver!

Comment: now you can probably make this even smoother by storing the settings in service also and make for less arguments in the function. A simple way to start would be combine `$scope.pageSize` and `$scope.currentPage` into one object

Comment: Great advice! Just to make sure I'm following you correctly, you mean I can create an object, such as `$scope.pagination`, then set it: `$scope.pagination.pageSize = 10; $scope.pagination.currentPage = 0;`
And then pass that object as one argument, right?

Comment: yes or even set it right in service when controller loads...then settings are available without needing function argument, or vice versa and pull settings defaults from service and modify if needed within each controller

Comment: that's a great idea, i've never thought of taking that approach. thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: whole idea is to have controllers do as little as possible...keep them very lean. It's a whole lot easier extending functionality in a service that may affect multiple controllers than the other way around